# duplicate columns when using join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to join two tables: `trainSearchStream` and `SearchInfo` based on a common column: `SearchID`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   trainSearchStream
       INNER JOIN SearchInfo
               ON trainSearchStream.SearchID = SearchInfo.SearchID
LIMIT  3;
```

The problem is that the result has two columns for `SearchID`. How can I display only one column for `SearchID`?

These are the columns of `trainSearchStream`:

```
SearchID,AdID,Position,ObjectType,HistCTR,IsClick
```

and these are columns for `SearchInfo`:

```
 SearchDate,IPID,UserID,IsUserLoggedOn,SearchQuery,LocationID,CategoryID,SearchParams
```

My other question is that how can I save the result of my select statement in a new table?

Comment: can you post a sample output?

Comment: Which database are you using? MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: Sqlite3 @ColonelThirtyTwo

Comment: @MAS In the future, please only tag the database software you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the **`*`** in the `SELECT` list and give a specific list of columns to return.

```
  SELECT t.SearchID
       , t.AdID
       , t.Position
       , t.ObjectType
       , t.HistCTR
       , t.IsClick
       , i.SearchDate
       , i.IPID
       , i.UserID
       , i.IsUserLoggedOn
       , i.SearchQuery
       , i.LocationID
       , i.CategoryID
       , i.SearchParams
    FROM trainSearchStream t
    JOIN SearchInfo i 
      ON t.SearchID = i..SearchID
   LIMIT 3;
```

---

To "save" the result from that in another table, you can use an `INSERT ... SELECT` statemeent.  If you want to create a new table, you can use a `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` statement.

References:

[**`INSERT ... SELECT`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

[**`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: Also note: best practice is to qualify *all* column references with the table name  (or an a table alias), as shown in the example query. This avoids your statement from throwing an "ambiguous column reference" error in the future, if someone were to add a column to a table, e.g. adding `UserID` column to the `trainSearchStream` table. With column references qualified, the statement will continue to work. If a reference to `UserID` is not qualified, then the statement that was working will start throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Specify exactly the columns you want to see. This always the preferred way

```
SELECT 
t.SearchID,AdID,Position,ObjectType,HistCTR,IsClick,
SearchDate, IPID,UserID,IsUserLoggedOn,SearchQuery,LocationID,CategoryID,SearchParams
FROM trainSearchStream  t
INNER JOIN SearchInfo ON trainSearchStream.SearchID = SearchInfo.SearchID LIMIT 3;
```

**Edit**

I forgot to include the alias name and apply that to column `SearchId`.

Comment: I get Error: ambiguous column name: SearchID